# How to start spinning a bootstrap font awesome icon, then make it stop with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, settimeout, font-awesome

I have the font awesome refresh icon on a webpage that I am working on.

```
<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-3x" id="lock-refresh"></i>
```

When this icon is clicked, I want it to start spinning. I've been able to accomplish this by inputting the following in my JavaScript file:

```
$( '#lock-refresh' ).click(function() {
    $( this ).addClass( 'fa-spin' ).

    //Below is a function that I need to run after the FA icon is clicked.
    startup();
});
```

I only need this icon to spin for a couple of seconds, though. I've tried to add this (below) to my JS file, but when I do the icon does not spin at all:

```
$( '#lock-refresh' ).click(function() {
    $( this ).addClass( 'fa-spin' );

    //Trying to remove the class after 1000 milliseconds. Not working.
    $( this ).delay(1000).removeClass( 'fa-spin' );
    startup();
});
```

I've also tried the following, which doesn't work as well:

```
$( '#lock-refresh' ).click(function() {
    $( this ).addClass( 'fa-spin' ).delay(1000).removeClass( 'fa-spin' );
    startup();
});
```

I've also tried the following, but when I do this the icon starts spinning but won't stop:

```
$( '#lock-refresh' ).click(function() {
    $( this ).addClass( 'fa-spin' );

    //Trying to use setTimeout, but doesn't seem to work either.
    setTimeout(function() { $( this ).removeClass( 'fa-spin' ); }, 1000);
    startup();
});
```

I've tried all of the above without my `startup()` function, and it produces the same results so I'm sure it is not the function.

How do I get my FA refresh icon to spin for only a second or two, then stop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should do:

```
$( '#lock-refresh' ).click(function() {
    $( this ).addClass( 'fa-spin' );
    var $el = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() { $el.removeClass( 'fa-spin' ); }, 1000);
    startup();
    // Whatever here.
});
```

Because `this` was something else inside `setTimeout(function(){` and was not pointing to the clicked element.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3s9to9ab/)

Query's CSS manipulation isn't queued, but you can make it executed inside the 'fx' queue by doing:

```
 $( '#lock-refresh' ).click(function() {
        $(this).addClass("fa-spin").delay(1000).queue('fx', function() { $(this).removeClass('fa-spin'); });
        startup();
        // Whatever here.
 });
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3s9to9ab/3/)

Comment: Very straight-forward. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use `delay` method in this case because addClass doesn't return queue interface to work with delay.

So you should indeed use `setTimeout` but use correct `this` value inside. The problem is that setTimeout will execute callback function in global object (`this === window`) context. So you need to provide a proper context. For this, it's convenient to use [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method:

```
$( '#lock-refresh' ).click(function() {
    $( this ).addClass( 'fa-spin' );
    setTimeout(function() { 
        $( this ).removeClass( 'fa-spin' ); 
    }.bind(this), 1000);
    startup();
});
```

Comment: I gave @void the accepted answer, but just confirming that this works perfectly as well. Appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Do something like this(note: use setTimout instead of setInterval, my bad)
https://jsfiddle.net/c7276oww/

```
$( '#lock-refresh' ).click(function() {
    $( this ).addClass( 'fa-spin' );
    setTimeout(function(){ $( '#lock-refresh' ).removeClass( 'fa-spin' ); }, 3000);
    //Below is a function that I need to run after the FA icon is clicked.
    startup();
});
```

Comment: I gave @void the accepted answer, but this works perfectly as well. I appreciate the help. I got so caught up with using `$( this )` that I didn't think to just reference the actual element.